# Split string and switch output columns

Tags: awk, cut

My input is:

```
TGCCTCAGTTCAGCAGGAACAGT_1       __not_aligned
CGCCCGATCTCGTCTGATCTCG_0        __too_low_aQual
TTTTAACGCGGACCAGAAACTA_2        __not_aligned
TACCGTGTAGAACCGAATTTGT_69       mir-10
AGGAAGCCCTGGAGGGGCTGGAGA_0      mir-671
```

I want the output to be:

```
   __not_aligned    1
   __too_low_aQual  0
   __not_aligned  2
   mir-10    69
   mir-671          0
```

I was trying to use the cut function, but I am not sure how to switch the columns and how to get that specific output?

```
cut -d _ -f
```

Answer (score 2):

You may try this with gawk:

```
awk '{match($1,"[0-9]+",a)}{print $2,a[0]}' file
```

outputs:

```
__not_aligned 1
__too_low_aQual 0
__not_aligned 2
mir-10 69
mir-671 0
```

Or better with POSIX (thanks to Ed Morton):

```
 awk --posix '{match($1,/[0-9]+/);print $2,substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}' file
```

Comment: awk: syntax error at source line 1
 context is
  >>> {match($1,"[0-9]+", <<< 
awk: illegal statement at source line 1
awk: illegal statement at source line 1

Comment: Works for me with GNU awk 4.1.3 on cygwin. Can anyone reproduce the error, please?

Comment: First line in the file is like a header, maybe that is why: Seq_../trimmed/94R.tally.fasta  __not_aligned

Comment: The 3rd arg for match() is gawk-specific. Try running it as gawk --posix to see the error.

Comment: btw the 2nd arg to match() is a regexp so use regexp delimiters `/[0-9]+/` when specifying a regexp constant, don't use string delimiters `"[0-9]+"` which awk then has to convert to a regexp with undesirable side-effects (google it). To make this non-gawk-specific just get rid of `,a` from `match()` and change `a[0]` to `substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)`. Also, for clarity (and performance?) just put the 2 actions in one action block `{x; y}`, not 2 `{x}{y}`.

Comment: @EdMorton: Thanks, I added your recommendation to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '{sub(/[^_]+_/,""); print $2, $1}' file
__not_aligned 1
__too_low_aQual 0
__not_aligned 2
mir-10 69
mir-671 0
```

.

```
$ sed -r 's/[^_]+_([0-9]+)[[:space:]]+(.*)/\2 \1/' file
__not_aligned 1
__too_low_aQual 0
__not_aligned 2
mir-10 69
mir-671 0
```

Comment: I come up with almost same awk one-liner `awk '{sub(/.*_/,"",$1);print $2,$1}'` ... up!

Comment: why? I gave `$1` as parameter... not $0

Answer (score 0):

you can try use `sed` instead of `cut`

```
sed 's/[ACGT]\+_\([0-9]\+\)[ \t]\+\([^ \t]\+\)/\2\t\1/g' file
```

you get

```
__not_aligned   1
__too_low_aQual 0
__not_aligned   2
mir-10  69
mir-671 0
```

Answer (score 0):

If Perl is an option:

```
perl -lne 'if (/^([ACGT]+)_(\d+)\s+(.*)/){print "$3 $2"}' file
```

Capture 3 fields into a regex:
`^([ACGT]+)` starting with one or more ACGT bases, followed by an underscore
`(\d+)` one or more numerals, followed by `\s+` whitespace
`(.*)` anything

If the regex matches, print the 3rd field and the 2nd field

Answer (score -1):

If you really want to use `cut`, combine it with `paste` to get your output:

```
paste <(tr -s '\t ' < foo.txt | cut -f 2 -d ' ') <(cut -f 1 -d ' ' foo.txt | cut -f 2 -d _)

__not_aligned   1
__too_low_aQual 0
__not_aligned   2
mir-10  69
mir-671 0
```